# What is the Lua equivalent of Twisted Python, Eventmachine for Ruby, NIO for Java, etc.?

Tags: networking, sockets, lua, twisted

What is the Lua equivalent of Twisted Python, Eventmachine for Ruby, NIO for Java, etc.?

If there is none, how does one do non-blocking event-based network I/O?

In general, how does one solve the C10K problem in Lua?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine recently begun the project [Lua Event Machine](https://github.com/esmil/lem), which should be a kind of *Node.js, just in Lua*.

(Haven't tried it myself, you I cant make any guarantees on the project's awesomeness...)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [lua-ev](http://github.com/brimworks/lua-ev) is your best bet.

Comment: Eeek this is horrible looking:
http://github.com/brimworks/lua-ev/blob/master/test/test_ev_io.lua#L50-L106

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all the buzzwords in your question, but looking up the C10K problem suggested that Lua coroutines in the context of the [Kepler project](http://www.keplerproject.org/) might be helpful.  That would certainly be the place I would go to create a highly performant Web app using Lua and serving large numbers of clients.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question as well. Copas might be enough, or ConcurrentLua or Lua Lanes.

Answer (score -4):

Node.js. Javascript isn't too much different from Lua and node is crazy fast.